# Is there an equivalent of Javascript's optional chaining in Java?

Tags: java

> ```js
> String answer = question1?.question2?.answer
> ```

Is there a way (preferably in-built) to get the property of an object where both the following scenarios are covered:

1. If the object is null, return a null value for the attribute.
2. Returns null for an attribute if it doesn't exist in the object.

To top this, is there a way to chain such get operations for deeply nested attributes?

Comment: Java doesn't have this feature, I'm pretty sure this is one of the areas that Kotlin did a great job at improving upon. Null checks in Java are typically done with if statements or `Optional`

Comment: I find a optionals  if I [search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+optional+chaining+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: No. Some people use the new `Optional` that was added in Java 8, but it is discouraged to use it that way.

Comment: Why tf these downvotes? Is it a bad or a wrong question??

Comment: @Andreas do you have a link to an official/authoritative source discouraging this practice?

Comment: @ChambreNoire [Stuart Marks has a nice talk about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14).

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't however Groovy does.  When writing Groovy you can mix java right in with it.  In Groovy you can do println company?.address?.street?.name

Comment: I like this idea, very much.

Answer (score -4):

it's possible to obtain "similar" behavior(chain) but just with custom code ( not being something inbuild)

```
public class TestChain 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        TestChain tc = new TestChain();
        Person p = tc. new Person();
        p.setName("pName").getMsg().setAge(10).getMsg();
    }
    
    class Person
    {
        String name;
        int age;
        public Person setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }
        
        public Person setAge(int age)
        {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }
        
        public Person getMsg()
        {
            System.out.println(this);
            return this;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return "name="+name+",age="+age;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
name=pName,age=0
name=pName,age=10
```

Basically methods to be chained need to return current instance.